# oData WCF Data Services Filter Child Collection

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-data-services, odata

I have an array of customers, each customer has a collection of orders.

the query below returns customers and their orders and works as expected:

```
~Customers?$expand=Orders
```

Now I want to get the existing customers but filter their orders by Order.Amount > 100 (I'm happy for the customers having no such orders to remain in the list),

When I'm trying the following:

```
~Customers?$expand=Orders&$filter=Orders/Amount gt 100
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
The 'Amount' is not allowed at position ***. Member access or specifying a type identifier on a resource set reference is not allowed.
```

I can loop through the customers and call

```
~Customers('Blah')/Orders?$filter=Amount gt 100
```

which works, but I'd really like to get it done in one go.

Could you advice on how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two things causing problems here. First, it sounds like you want to filter the Orders collection, not the Customers collection (i.e., you always want all Customers to be returned, but you only want certain Orders to be expanded). When you have a URI that looks like `EntitySet?$filter=<some predicate>`, the filter always applies to the `EntitySet`, which in your case is `Customers` (which is not what you want).

Secondly, the reason `~Customers?$expand=Orders&$filter=Orders/Amount gt 100` doesn't even filter the Customers correctly is because `Orders` is a collection of entities, not a single entity. `Orders/Amount` doesn't make sense if you think of Orders as a list, only `Order/Amount` does. If you wanted to have a filter that only returns Customers who have at least one Order where `Order/Amount` is greater than 100, you could use the `any` keyword:

```
~Customers?$expand=Orders&$filter=Orders/any(o: o/Amount ge 100)
```

But again, that filters the Customers, not the Orders.

Given that you want to actually be filtering the Orders, would the following work for you?

```
~Orders?$expand=Customer&$filter=Amount gt 100
```

Comment: I understand that in terms of classic LINQ it's SelectMay, I was just looking for the most elegant way of doing so...

Comment: OData's query syntax doesn't have support for the SelectMany idea. That last line should do what you need though, right?