# Dynamic LINQ select from relational tables

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a db that has a central table, with more than 30 tables referenced by a FK.  An entry will always have a row in the main table, and depending on the type of information, may be in 1 or 2 (I currently can't think of any scenario where it is in more than 2) of the associated tables.

Depending on the customer, only the tables that are being populated are represented to the end user, and they can dynamically choose which columns of information are returned to them.

I am using Entity Framework to access the records and have found a speed dilemma with all of the referenced tables.  If I just do something like:

```
var v = from r in context.Records
select r;
```

When it does the query, it is also doing a sub query for each individual associated table, whether it has entries or not.  When on a local lan that is in good shape, its fast, but has a noticeable delay.  When remotely running these queries, it can take most of a second per record to run all the associated queries.  A sample of the associated queries is at the bottom of this post.  I created an entity model that only had a handful of tables instead of the full set for demo purposes and got the log output from EF.  I only pasted the output from 1 record query set.

As such, my thought was to use linq to put together something along the lines of

```
var v = from r in context.Records
        select new { ID = r.ID, val1 = r.val1, val2=r.val2, val3 = r.child_table1.val1, r.child_table1.val2 };
```

This did exactly what I wanted as far as removing the overhead of the unneeded queries and removed the performance issue....(here comes where I'm currently stuck).

However, the child_table and column names are the part that has to be dynamic.  I will always be pulling the columns for the main table, but I need to dynamically create the portion of the select that relates to the columns off of the related table.

For example, a customer may only have 3 child tables that are being populated and therefore the rest are not needed.  But as we have many customers across the world, everyone is different so it's not practical to code up every possible scenario, nor maintainable as we are always updating/adding as we need to handle new things.

So for my normal scenario, I need 2-4 child tables, and all of the columns for each.  I can govern what columns are presented from the ui.  The biggest challenge is only querying the child tables that actually have rows in them.

Hopefully I'm overthinking this and someone will give me an aha moment.

Any thoughts or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
    SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[records] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
-- Executing at 11/29/2013 9:03:02 PM -05:00
-- Completed in 20 ms with result: SqlDataReader

SELECT TOP (128) 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---]
    FROM [dbo].[records] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[ID] ASC
-- Executing at 11/29/2013 9:03:02 PM -05:00
-- Completed in 67 ms with result: SqlDataReader

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---]
    FROM [dbo].[meta_---] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[RecordID] = @EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int64)
-- Executing at 11/29/2013 9:03:03 PM -05:00
-- Completed in 25 ms with result: SqlDataReader

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---]
    FROM [dbo].[meta_---2] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int64)
-- Executing at 11/29/2013 9:03:03 PM -05:00
-- Completed in 20 ms with result: SqlDataReader

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---]
    FROM [dbo].[meta_---3] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int64)
-- Executing at 11/29/2013 9:03:03 PM -05:00
-- Completed in 18 ms with result: SqlDataReader

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---]
    FROM [dbo].[meta_---4] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int64)
-- Executing at 11/29/2013 9:03:03 PM -05:00
-- Completed in 30 ms with result: SqlDataReader

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---]
    FROM [dbo].[meta_---5] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int64)
-- Executing at 11/29/2013 9:03:03 PM -05:00
-- Completed in 23 ms with result: SqlDataReader

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---], 
    [Extent1].[---] AS [---]
    FROM [dbo].[meta_---6] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int64)
-- Executing at 11/29/2013 9:03:03 PM -05:00
-- Completed in 18 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

Comment: If you have many customers around the world, why do you use such a bad design in the DB? :)
You can also consider to use .Include method which will only include references that you need for a particular scenario.

Comment: You may use keyvaluepair list to save the query, then use Reflection and Expression to build linq dynamically, I don't know if it's you wanted and I'm using the solution to solve the similar problem.

Comment: I have yet to see a better design.  I have seen several bad attempts that involve a single flat table for all columns which is the epitome of bad design.  It's a relational db for a reason.  The parts that are common to all are in 1 spot, the other pieces are where they should be.  

As for the .Include, it doesn't address the problem.  The other unneeded tables are still queried which is what I want to eliminate.

Comment: Chris, could you possibly post a small sample to explain what you mean?

Comment: big top EF dynamic linq.  Many related questions. eg http://stackoverflow.com/a/17971663/1347784

Comment: I've read all of those posts but either don't understand them enough to apply to my scenario, or they don't quite fit what I need.  I'm not trying to create and/or where clauses.  I need to dynamically create the Select portion.  To reiterate, hopefully clearer, I need to pull all columns from a set of tables.  The set of tables in question is what is dynamic.  In all cases, it will include the main table, and then on a case by case basis, any combination of the other 30 tables.  So I need the select portion to only reference the columns in the desired tables that is determined at runtime.